# How to include one java file into another java file both having the main functions in it?

Tags: java, file, class, user-interface, program-entry-point

I want to include one java file into another. Both have the main functions in it. One file looks similar to the following:

```
public class FileShow
{

 public static void main(String args[])
  {

        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("RTL Parser GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(500,500);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField handle = new JTextField(30);
        comboPanel.add(handle);

    guiFrame.add(comboPanel);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

whereas my other java file is:

```
public class AnotherFile{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AnotherFile();
    }

    public AnotherFile()
    {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Assertion-Based GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(500,500);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField handle = new JTextField(30);
        comboPanel.add(handle);

    guiFrame.add(comboPanel);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine both the files and run together, since both have the main functions in it?
How do i combine both the files in same java file and run both of them together?

Comment: did you compile your code?

Comment: i compiled it separately.

Comment: Try again. In class AnotherFile, guiFrame = new JFrame(); it would rise an error, sicnce you have not declared which class's object is guiFrame. Then you can compile. It should be JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

Comment: ohk, i have declared JFrame as public class, i forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 4):

You just can't do that. Each Java file should have only one `main` method.

But you can better organize your files to do what you want:

```
public class FileShow{

    public void doSomething(){
    //...
    }

}

public class AnotherFile{

    public void doSomething(){
    //...
    }

}

public class mainClass(){
    public static void main(String args[])
         new FileShow().doFileShow();               
         new AnotherFile().doAnotherFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add 'AnotherFile' object in the main method of Fileshow. You can only have one main method.

So in Fileshow.java, in the main method add

```
Anotherfile a = new Anotherfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, it is completely unclear, what you want to achieve. Include two Java classes into one .java file? Into one .jar file?
What do you mean by "run together"?

Combining two top-level Java classes in one source file is possible (according to JLS), while only one of them may be public. I believe though, it is not a best practice, just because you get quite a messy lifecycle of your classes. But if you still want to do it, you must make one of them either package private or nested.

Getting both to one jar is trivial. Just call `jar cf jarname <classes>`. It would also be possible to call the main methods separately by explicit mentioning them in java command line, like `java -cp jarname <package>.FileShow`.

Still, I'm not sure I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, each Java file can contain one public class and by default JDK will call it's main method. If you have two classes both having a main method and you want to keep it in one Java file, the two classes can not be public, one must be an [inner/nested class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). I have given an example below.

```
public class FileShow
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         AnotherFile.main(args);;
         // Your code
     }

     static class AnotherFile
     { // as it contains a static method

        public static void main(String[] args) //or any static class
        {
           new AnotherFile();
        }
        public AnotherFile(){
         // Your code
        }
     }
}
```

Logically it will work. But I **highly discourage** to go with this. It is not standard.